# AngularJS - Replace values in array based on input text box changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a simple text box -

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputID" name="ItemId" ng-model="inputItemId" ng-required="true" ng-blur="addValueToArray(inputItemId)"/>
```

The number of input boxes increase and decrease based on the user's choice (I have a simple add/subtract functionality that replicates the text boxes or removes them), but they ultimately are all stored in an array -

```
        $scope.itemIDs = [];
        $scope.addValueToArray = function(inputItemId)
        {       
            $scope.validID = $filter('uppercase')(inputItemId); 
            $scope.itemIDs.push($scope.validID);        
        }
```

My $scope.itemIDs array holds all the IDs the user has entered in the various text boxes.

Say the values in this array right now are - ABC,ABD,ABE,ABZ for four different items.

What I wish to achieve now is, if a user decides to remove the second value ABD and replace it with ABW in the text box, based on how my function works, it ends up adding it after the last element of the array and looks like - ABC,ABD,ABE,ABZ, ABW.

Is there a way in angular where I could replace the entered value of the second value with the new one in the array instead of adding it in the end? Am I missing out on something?

Comment: Try use `array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)` for this. see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,
`$scope.itemIDs = [];
  $scope.addValueToArray = function(oldValue,newValue){ 
    $scope.itemIDs[$scope.itemIDs.indexOf(oldValue)] = newValue;
  }`